# Why object keys passed as an array element throw a syntax error in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Say: `arr1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']` and `arr2 = [0, 1, 2]`

We want an object `{'a' : 0}`

This function throws a syntax error:

```
function makeObject(arr1, arr2) {
  return {arr1[0] : arr2[0]}
}
```

but this is okay:

```
function makeObject(arr1, arr2) {
  return {[arr1[0]] : arr2[0]}
}
```

Why and where can I find more documentation on this behavior?

Comment: Computed property names

Comment: You always have to use square brackets when defining a property name with a variable. The only time you can omit them is when the property name is going to be a plain pre-defined string.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names